# Cache-Control to be cached for one minute

Tags: node.js

```
function sendData(response, code, data, mime) {
    response.writeHead(code, {
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(data, 'binary'),
        'Content-Type': mime,
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=60'
    })
    response.write(data, 'binary')
    response.end()
}
```

This is my code, I am trying to cache everything for one minute, it is quite straightforward, but each time I click reload in the browser, all files are downloaded again. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Do you have the dev tools open?

Comment: @generalhenry, I can close or open the dev tools, why?

Comment: By default when the dev tools are open the browser ignores the cache

Answer (score 1):

Cache-Control headers are a recommendation to the browser but they **are** allowed to call your server again before the cache expires - which they will do when the user presses the refresh button.

Comment: Also it's worth to try to open the page in new tab/window instead of reload.